# Как открыть 2 ветки одного проекта в Visual studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

Можно ли открыть два экземпляра Visual Studio с одним и тем же решением из одного репозитория но что бы можно было выбрать для каждого решения свою ветку? Сейчас, если я открываю два экземпляра среды, то ветки у обеих решений одинаковые а если попытаться поменять ветку то меняется она соответсвенно тоже у обеих решений сразу

Comment: Нет, т.к. VS делает лишь графический интерфейс над GIT, а GIT так не может. Вы переключаете ветки - гит подменяет файлы в папке на другие. Вы можете переключить ветки из командной строки GIT и убедиться, что они также переключатся и в VS. Решение - хранить отдельно два репозитория

Comment: А существуют альтернативы которые так умеют?

Comment: А зачем вообще это может понадобиться?

Comment: https://stacktoheap.com/blog/2016/01/19/using-multiple-worktrees-with-git/

Comment: https://inoyakaigor.ru/blog/85

Comment: @АндрейNOP, только ему ещё и два бранча делать надо будет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP за советы вроде *"Ошибка fatal: '' is already checked out at '' (fatal: «…» уже находится на …) ... лечится удалением директории .git/worktrees/ "* поубивал бы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хорошо, что это не мой блог. Я жить еще хочу!

Answer (score 6):

Если git у вас свежий - можете использовать [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree):

```
git worktree add [-b <НоваяВетка>] <Путь> <Ветка>
```

После этого по указанному вами пути появится копия репозитория, но уже с другой активной веткой.

К сожалению, студия с такими рабочими копиями работать не умеет, поэтому коммиты придется делать с помощью какого-нибудь другого средства (рекомендую Git Extensions).

Если же у вас старая версия гита или вы хотите продолжать использовать студию для работы с гитом - остается только клонировать репозиторий в другую папку и работать с двумя разными репозиториями.

Comment: `К сожалению, студия с такими рабочими копиями работать не умеет` -- ну то есть для нормальной работы в VS таки мой способ - единственный :)

Comment: @n01d студия много чего не умеет, то есть единственный нормальный способ работы с гитом - без нее

Comment: `появится копия репозитория` — даже само название команды (worktree) как бы намекает: копия не репозитория там появится, а рабочего каталога (рабочего «дерева», если буквально перевести).

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. Как уже ответил @АндрейNOP, GIT подменяет файлы в папке при изменении ветки (делает checkout на другую ветку).

Единственный вариант — склонировать репозиторий ещё раз в другую папку и открыть эту другую папку.

Comment: Таки не единственный, worktree же есть...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ого, не знал, спасибо! Проверю, умеет ли с такой радостью VSCode работать)