# Как работать одновременно с 2-мя ветками?

Tags: visual-studio, git

Допустим, у меня есть ветки, и в один момент мне хочется открыть их одновременно в Visual Studio, чтобы не выполнять переключение между ними.

Как я могу это сделать или единственный варик, сделать клонирование в другую директорию?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774565/190728 git worktree. Как новый клон, но гораздо легче

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть 2 ветки одного проекта в Visual studio 2017?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-visual-studio-2017)